# Unable to connect to GCP CloudSQL using Private IP address (CORS error preflight missing allow origin header)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, ioexception, hikaricp

I am using GCP Cloud SQL instances for getting data. This SQL instance when accessed with its public IP address, connection is happening and data is visible. But due to security constraint I will have to access it only via private IP address.

I made code changes as said in Google documentations for connection via private IP address:
(https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard#private-ip_1)
(https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#java-8)

1. In **ConnectionPoolContextListener.java** file: iptypes=Private added

config.addDataSourceProperty("ipTypes", "PRIVATE");

2. In **appengine-web.xml** file: serverless vpc connector element added

projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/europe-west1/connectors/CONNECTORNAME
        all-traffic

3. In **gitlab-ci.yml** file: line to deploy the connector service added

deploy_env-name:
script:-gcloud app deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml

These changes are not working and the API calls made are failing giving CORS errors(cross origin resource sharing error preflight missing allow origin header)(refer to screenshot)
[UI CORS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBPO4.png)

**App engines logs are as follows:**
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool throwPoolInitializationException: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. (HikariPool.java:587)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused

Everything is working when public IP address is used no CORS error also. But with private IP address connection is failing, not sure what is wrong here.

DB Connection code:

```
private DataSource createConnectionPool() {
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:postgresql://google/%s", 
DB_NAME));
config.setUsername(DB_USER);
config.setPassword(DB_PASS); 
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", 
"com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", 
CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
config.addDataSourceProperty("ipTypes", "PRIVATE");
config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
config.setMinimumIdle(5);
config.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 10 seconds
config.setIdleTimeout(600000); // 10 minutes
config.setMaxLifetime(1800000); // 30 minutes
DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);
return pool;
}
```

Comment: Just ticking the boxes... the VPC Access connector was created in the same project and same region as the App Engine instance, correct? How long has the AppEngine been there? Is it really old? Check on the networking page that you don't see "Legacy" tagging the network where your App Engine lives. Barring those, including some code for the connection would be helpful (obviously remove password/user info, but the connection string would be good just to be sure it's formatted right).

Comment: Oh, and do you have CORS headers on your app now? Or was it just magically working before and now it's not?

Comment: The VPC connector is in the same region as that of App engine instance. The app engine network is not tagged as Legacy.

CORS headers are not added yet. But I get the CORS error only when I disable public IP address access and the app works fine after I enable public IP back. I had tried adding CORS headers once, I faced issues on App engine version traffic migration that time, the traffic migration was failing.

Comment: The CORS error is unrelated and probably thrown by a failed HTTP request. The real issue is, why is your connection refused?

Comment: So seeing the connection string (without credentials) and knowing what kind of database you're connecting to would help (mysql, postgres, etc).

Comment: Hi @enocom, I am using Postgres DB. I have edited the question and added DB Connection Pool code.

Answer (score 1):

There was something wrong in VPC connector that I had created before. I created a new VPC connector with same network and region as those of the cloudsql instance and assigned an IP address range and now this DB connection is happening and data is getting loaded and CORS error has gone.

So to connect to a SQL instance via Private IP address from App engine I had to make only the following changes:

1. Create a Serverless VPC connector.
2. add vpc-connector element in appengine.yml file
3. include property "iptypes" in ConnectionPoolContextListener.java file

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem. The connection string has an error in it:

```java
// Not correct
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:postgresql://google/%s", DB_NAME));

// Should be
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:postgresql:///%s", DB_NAME));
```

See the documentation for details: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md#creating-the-jdbc-url.

Comment: Hi @enocom ,I made this change in JDBC URL and checked other properties also against this documentation, still same error.

Comment: I verified this works. Here's what I did: I started with https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/cloud-sql/postgres/servlet. I added a vpc access connector setting to my appengine-web.xml pointing at my access connector. Then I deployed and saw it all work. I'd suggest going through the same exercise to figure out what detail might be missing.